# Existence of a homeomorphism that does not return much

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ a homeomorphism where $X$ is a compact metric space.

Fix $x\in X$, denote $O(f,x)=\{ f^n(x):n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ the orbit of $f$ by $x$.

For $m\in \mathbb{N}$ denote $O(f,x,m)=\{ f^j(x): \vert j\vert \leq m\}$ and $\#(A)$ is the cardinal of $A$.

I am interested in the existence of an example of $f$ such that: there is $\delta>0$ with the following property

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{m\to\infty}}\frac{\#(B[z,\delta]\cap O(f,x,m))}{\#(O(f,x,m))}=0$$
where $z\in \overline{O(f,x)}\setminus O(f,x)$ and $B[z,\delta]$ is the ball closed.

I appreciate if you could give me some suggestion to know if such homeomorphism exists.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I don't get that. Since $z\in \overline{O(f,x)}\setminus O(f,x)$ I don't think that $$\#\left(B[z,\delta]\cap O(f,x,m)\right)$$ can stay bounded right?

Comment: In that limit, $z$ and $x$ are both fixed with $f$, I am assuming.

Comment: @Pjotr5: Yes, I misread the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to find such points for the full shift: $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb Z}$, $f(x)_n=x_{n+1}$. Take an $x$ that is mainly zero, but also has arbitrarily long intervals of $1$'s, for example
$$
x_n = \begin{cases} 1 & 2^k\le n \le 2^k + k \\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases} .
$$
Then $z_n=1$ is in the orbit closure, but $f^n x$ can only be close to $z$ if $n\approx 2^k$, so the limit is indeed zero for all small $\delta>0$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the  problem only is fixed $x$.  It will be possible to obtain the result for all $z\in \overline{O(f,x)}\setminus O(f,x)$ ?

Comment: @helmonio: No. For $z=0$, the limit is $1$. It is equal to zero for everything else in the orbit closure (sequence that switch from $0$ to $1$ at one point, or vice versa).

Comment: It is in fact not possible to have the limit equal to zero for *all* $z$ for a fixed $\delta$; this contradicts compactness.